# How do I get rid of this whitespace?

Tags: html, html-email

I'm doing some HTML for the first time, creating an email signature.

```
<font face ="Calibri"> Regards,<br>
Daniel Steele </font>
<p> <font face ="Calibri" size="4"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;     Systems Developer </font>
<TABLE BORDER="0" cellpadding="0" CELLSPACING="0">
  <TR>
    <TD WIDTH="306" HEIGHT="106" BACKGROUND="http://i.imgur.com/VGY3iMz.png" VALIGN="centre"><font size="1"> <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      </font> <font face ="Calibri" size="3" color="#FFFFFF"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 01753 480818 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 0787251 2509 </font>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

It's pretty straight forward. However, there's a significant space between the job title and the image. I can't work out how to get rid of it!
Any ideas/workarounds?

Comment: Using whitespace & `<br>`s to position text will likely produce unexpected results in many email clients, in particular those on machines without Calibri.  Clients will also often block the image unless its inline.

Comment: in which mail client?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of the automated `CSS` for the `<p>` tag.
All you have to do is to add `style="margin: 0;"` to your `<p>`, like this:

```
<p style="margin: 0;"> <font face ="Calibri" size="...etc
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v2BXP/)

Answer (score 0):

Better use tables for this. Remember instead of `<br>` you can close your td and tr and create a new tr. This code does what I suggest you to do in the html-email generally

```
<table cellpadding="0" CELLSPACING="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <font face ="Calibri">
        Regards,
      </font>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <font face ="Calibri">
        Daniel Steele 
      </font>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>

        <font face ="Calibri" size="4">
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;     Systems Developer 
        </font>
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <TABLE BORDER="0" cellpadding="0" CELLSPACING="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <TR>
          <TD WIDTH="306" HEIGHT="106" BACKGROUND="http://i.imgur.com/VGY3iMz.png" VALIGN="centre">
            <font size="1">

              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
            </font>

            <font face ="Calibri" size="3" color="#FFFFFF">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 01753 480818 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 0787251 2509 
            </font>
          </TD>
        </TR>
      </TABLE>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

also instead of using too much spaces you could create an empty td there(remember to use one   in empty tds). Will not do that for you :P, good luck.

**

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yAn2q/1/)

**

Comment: I agree to rather use table for everything but using (<br/>) & ($ nbsp ;) is unnecessary and could result in unexpected results specially since it will be read in email clients

Comment: yes edited the answer forgot to put br inside code and it wasnt visible.